# Changed Image with same url is not reloaded in IE

Tags: javascript, asp.net, image, caching, cross-browser

In my asp.net project, I have a view－image page and an upload－image page. I upload an new image and direct to the view page, the image doesn't be changed, because IE won't reload the image if the image's url remains the same.

Any ideas? prefer the way to ask the browser to reload the image independently without server setting or web-headers changes.

Regards

Comment: Have you tried passing a randomized querystring parameter to the image's URL (for example `images/myimage.jpg?s=453462`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered putting a parameter after the image URL and changing that each time?

```
<img src="logo.jpg?rand=12345" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Unforunately you are going to have to add these Meta Tags

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="EXPIRES" CONTENT="0">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
```

These should force the browser not to cache anything and check for a new image every time

Comment: Ok in principle, but this is A). nothing like enough to decache reliably (you need swathe of 20 headers to do this with any kind of consistency), B). overly aggressive (what if I want to cache the CSS? the JS? other images than this one?) and C). up to the client to choose whether to respect anyway.

Comment: Very good point. Didnt think that far ahead.. It is possible to use javascript though to create a new image object - which then should overwrite the cache of the existing image. i.e var image = new Image(); image.src= 'source-to-new-image.jpg'; However its always a little unreliable too